# Pass data to input property in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and I'm doing this quiz, where I found the following question which I can't answer:

```
Let's consider the component <app-user> with an input property named user.
At line 6 what should we replace the ???? with, to pass data to this input property?

 1 import { Component } from '@angular/core'
 2 
 3 @Component({
 4   selector: 'my-app',
 5   template: `
 6      <app-user ????="user">
 7      </app-user>
 8   `
 9 )}
10 export class AppComponent  {
11   user = {
12     name: 'John Doe',
13     email: 'johndoe@mail.com',
14     age: 35,
15   }
16 }
```

So what I don't get:
Why do I need a `@Component` together with a class `AppComponent`?

And when I want to use the `user` property from the `app-user` component, why do I need to do it like this: `[user]="user"` and not just like `[user]` without the quote at the end?

Comment: If you're learning Angular, you might as well go through this tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial. It introduces some of the basics. In your specific case it'd be `<app-user [user]="user">`. To understand it, look into [data binding syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the input property name is defined by the `app-user` component. this is well covered in the angular.io docs for [component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

i.e

- if your `app-user` component has an @Input() user: User
- then when you call this component in HTML you would do `<app-user [user]="xxxxx"></app-user>`

Comment: So why is now `xxxx` in quotes?

Comment: xxx represents whatever value you want to pass to the child component. in your case it would be `<app-user [user]="user"></app-user>`  the [user] defined the input property you are passing to the child component. and the value in the quotes is what will be passed to the child component.

Comment: So `"user"` is like a default value?

Comment: no, there are no default values. the value comes from how the child component is defined. I think you might be getting confused by the word `user`. let's look at another example. if your `app-user` component had `@Input()  userData: UserDataInterface` in the component. you would call it as follows `<app-user [userData]="user"></app-user>`. the "user" in the HTML is the value defined in the app.component.ts that you provided in your example. this is the value being provided from the parent to the child component. the value you put between brackets has to match the value defined after @Input()

Answer (score 0):

In your component `app-user` you can have this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  template: `
    {{ user.name }}
  `
})
class AppUser {
    @Input() user: any; // Since your variable is named user your attribue on app-user to pass a value is 'user'
}
```

You should take a look at https://angular.io/api/core/Input from the Angular documentation.